# Read file line by line using C++ Program in linux system with each line in file has \r\n in the end

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a windows file in linux system line by line and each line of the file ending with \r\n. I don't want to change the carriage return at the end but want to read the file content as it is. Below code doesn't give me expected result in linux but works well in windows system. Some help here appreciated.

```
string myText;

// Read from the text file
ifstream MyReadFile("abcd.txt");

// Use a while loop together with the getline() function to read the file line by line
while (getline(MyReadFile, myText)) {
    // Output the text from the file
    cout << myText;
}

// Close the file
MyReadFile.close();
```

Tried reading a windows file line by line in linux system with c++

Comment: i think you can define your own delimiter when a new line starts. But you have to cope with the fact, that a file is possible not for unix but for windows with CRLF at the end.

Comment: `getline` assumes that the file is "a valid text file" for the system you are using, So you have to fix this either beforehand, or by discarding the `\r` after reading a line. (In the old days when we used ftp to transfer files between systems, this transformation happened during the transfer).

Comment: "doesn't give me expected result" *What* is your expected result? What is the result you are getting? Please post a [mcve] so that we can see for ourselves.